# Can Spring's @Cacheable annotation have the same scope as the annotated method's bean?

Tags: java, spring

Is there an easy way to use Spring's `@Cacheable` annotation with a non-singleton (e.g. session-scoped) bean and have the cache have the same scope as said bean?

Example:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

@Named
@Scope("session")
public class UserNameRetriever {

    @Inject private UserDao userDao;

    @Cacheable("userName")
    public String getUserName() {
        return userDao.getUserByLogin((String)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getName();
    }

}
```

Ideally, `UserNameRetriever.getUserName()` would fetch the username from the `UserDao` once per session, but this code actually caches application-wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but according to [Spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-spel-context) I think this would work:

```
@Cacheable(value = "userName", key = "#root.target")
```

Comment: This works, but has a memory leak without
(
 \@CacheEvict(value = "userName", key="#root.target")
 \@PreDestroy
 public void cleanup() {
 }
)
Also, I've decided not to use @Cacheable after all, since it does not guarantee that the value will be computed only once.

Comment: What do you mean by memory leak? Maybe your cache is too large. @Cacheable will lookup in cache first, so it guarantees that the value won't be computed while is still in cache.

Comment: It's a memory leak because once the session ends, the value is still in cache, but can't be accessed.  The @PreDestroy ensures that the cached value is evicted when the session ends.

Comment: This is not a memory leak, and it's very usual in cache usage.

Comment: Using a default setup of SimpleCacheManager and ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean, the cache appears to have an unbounded size, so I would consider it a memory leak to create a cache entry per session and never evict said entry.  I also think that evicting once the session dies is a better solution than limiting the cache size for this use case, since I don't want the value to change throughout the lifetime of the session.

Comment: I'm also starting to think that, as others have mentioned, this isn't what Cacheable is intended for, and I should just use the bean's internal caching I was using earlier to implement use cases of this nature.

Comment: if you want @Cacheable only for a session, you can use CacheManager bean with Session scope (the same works with request scope, if you want cache only for a request)

Answer (score 5):

If you want a session cache, use the session. That is, store the user in a private field in the session-scoped bean, or access the `HttpSession` object directly. `@Cacheable` is generally meant for application-wide resources.

Well, you can use `key="#user.id"`, and to invalidate the cache (manually or with `@CacheEvict`) on a `@PreDestroy` method, but it would be better if you don't mix the two - caching and session data.

Comment: Hi @Bozho could you please justify why you think it's better to use httpsession vs Cacheable in a spring web application?

Comment: it's session-wide vs application-wide resources. It's additional effort if you want to use @Cacheable for session resources

Answer (score 1):

I think you are approaching the problem from the wrong side. Instead of having "*local*" session-scoped caches storing only one value have one global cache storing a map from user name to `User` values.

In your case drop `@Cacheable` on `getUserName()` and put it on `UserDao`:

```
public class UserDao {
  @Cacheable("users")
  public User getUserByLogin(String user) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Not only this is more idiomatic usage of cache, but also it will prove to be easier to maintain and better performing.

Back to your original question: no, this is not possible out-of-the-box. You would have to write your own [`CacheManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) - probably a [decorator](/questions/tagged/decorator) around existing implementation.

Comment: RE: I think you are approaching the problem from the wrong side: UserDao fetches the user from an external system, and I want the username (used only cosmetically) to be consistent throughout a session, but refresh in a new session if it has changed in said external system.  Your approach would not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: if you want @Cacheable only for a session, you can use CacheManager bean with Session scope (the same works with request scope, if you want cache only for a request) –

Answer (score 0):

You can create CacheManager bean with Session (or Request if you want only for a request) scope.
It works perfectly fine.

```
  @Bean
  @SessionScope
  public CacheManager requestCacheManager() {
    return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
  }
```

Consider limiting/setting bounds for you cache (as some ppl mentioned about memory 'leaks')
So you can try using CaffeineCacheManager, where you can set maximum size, expire ttl etc.