# Make Spring's @Cacheable content live only during user session

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, browser-cache

While using Spring's @Cacheable, how to make sure the cache does not last longer than the actual session timeout?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151111/can-springs-cacheable-annotation-have-the-same-scope-as-the-annotated-methods

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your caches are defined as below,

```
@Cacheable("cacheName1")
public Map<String, List<String>> getMethod1(){
}

@Cacheable("cacheName2")
public Map<String, List<String>> getMethod2(){
}
```

then call below method while the user **clicks logout / session expires**.

```
@CacheEvict(value = { "cacheName1", "cacheName2"}, allEntries = true)
public void evictAllCache(){
    logger.info("All Cache Evict");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Extend CacheManager to handle bucket's name, e.g. #session_#name
2. Extend HttpSessionListener to make a clean up when session is destroyed

please find my draft sample of explicit cache per session below:
https://gist.github.com/pyanoveugen/b360622dc76136064b0215136f402837